Height adjustable cupboard for disabled
Wanting to make a kitchen cupboard move away from the wall and down 30 degrees and return to original position. Looked at the in-cupboard options but all to big. Can anyone help?

Google "kitchen cabinetry ADA"

Perhaps one of these Mixer lifts can be modified to work.
Truthfully more details are needed about the cabinet. Size weight, etc.
